# What does "self.default = default if default else type()" mean?

Tags: python

I have always been a .NET guy since I started working (~6 years). Recently, I am working on a project using Django, which requires me to learn Python in parallel. A lot of times I bumped into Python code that looked simple but I just couldn't understand. And here is one of them.

```
class TypedProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, name, type, default=None):
        self.name = "_" + name
        self.type = type
        self.default = default if default else type()
```

Can someone kindly explain to me what the last line of the code is doing?

I hope this question is not too trivial, as I am having trouble coming up with a good title for it.

Comment: I think that last line should be indented to be part of the \_\_init\_\_ method

Comment: Looks like an indentation error .. I guess the last line should align with its previous one (i.e. indented by 8 spaces).

Comment: not sure about the indentation.
I copied the code directly from the book, "Python Essential Reference"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a if b else c` is a conditional expression that evaluates to `a` if `b` evaluates to `True`, and to `c` otherwise.  In the given context, this checks if `default` is ["trucy"](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), in which case it is stored in `self.default`.  Otherwise, a new instance of `type` is created and stroed in `self.default`.

Note that this implementation has several issues:

1. It uses `type` as a variable name, shadowing the built-in `type()`.  This is considered bad style.
2. It uses the condition `if default` where actually `if default is None` should be used.  The check is intended to test if the parameter `default` was actually passed to the constructor.  As it is, the implementation won't accept any default value that [evaluates to `False`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: +1 Other "falsy" values include zeros, empty strings and empty collections. So it's usually better to use `if arg is not None: x = default` unless you know exactly you want to exclude those.

Answer (score 4):

In the function signature you see `default=None` - this means that if a third argument is not passed in, `default` will be equal to `None`.

That last line naively checks to see if `default` evaluates to true to determine if a default was passed in. If `default` is true, then `self.default` will be set to it. Otherwise `self.default` is set to an instance of the `type` passed in.

I say naively because `default` may be `0`, or it may be `False`, or (more likely) it may be an object, but that object evaluates to False somehow. I would prefer

```
self.default = default if default is not None else type()
```

Or, to avoid the conditional expression which I don't find the clearest in the world

```
if default is None:
    self.default = type()
else:
    self.default = default
```

Comment: +1  I'd personally write it as `self.default = default if (default is not None) else type()` even though the parentheses are redundant, it's less verbose than the 4 line version but slightly more readable than the 1-line without the parens.

Answer (score 1):

That is Python's ternary operator (aka [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)) in action! Something worth nothing is that Python evaluates booleans lazily, so in this case:

```
self.default = default if default else type()
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
self.default = default or type()
```

If `default` evaluates to any non-False value, its value would be used, otherwise it would fall through to `type()`.